# Report Builder Bar Start on a Gauge pointer

Tags: ssrs-2008-r2, reportbuilder3.0, gauge

I am trying to configure a Linear Gauge in Report Builder. I have defined two pointers one is the sum of valid items, the second is the sum of items affected by data quality.

There is a property called "Bar Start" which has two default values (Scalestart and Zero) which I am presuming sets where the start of the drawn bar is placed on the scale (i.e. if pointer value is 12 then bar goes from scalestart to 12).

I want my second pointer (DQ) to start where the first pointer (Valid) finishes. I have tried calculated values as an expression, I have tried a simple fixed value as an expression, but the bar always want to plot from the start of the scale.

Has anyone any ideas whether what I am trying to do is achievable, and if so, how I can do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Still using Linear Gauge, right mouse click and select add range. Modify the end and start values and change placement to outside. This maybe what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks - that doesn't quite do what I wanted. In the end I took a standard Bar graph and heavily modified it to look like a gauge.